# Check SQL Server database change in ASP.NET Core for pushing notifications

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net-core, notifications, sqldependency

I would like to know if there is a way to check if a SQL Server database changed based on some query.

I've already tried `SqlDependency`, but i think it's restricted on the inner join and simple selection queries, and I've read that it has memory leak problem.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use SignalR if you have any .net core function to make changes in database.

Comment: What do you mean by checking for changes in the first place? SqlDependency isn't restricted by joins. It doesn't have memory leaks, incorrect client code does. It provides near-real time notifications though, something you may not want. In fact, you may not even need to check the database if all changes are made from .NET code on the server side. You could send a notification from the server code each time a modification operation succeeded

Comment: If you *don't* need real-time updates, and there's a chance the data can be modified outside the server app's control, you could enable change tracking on the tables you care about and poll for changes periodically

Comment: The server will not be responsible for the data change it's another client.
so i need to check if some data changed on certain tables.

Comment: This doesn't scale beyond a few clients. This isn't a SqlDependency limitation, client/server architectures simply don't scale as well as three-tier applications do. Using the Message Broker system that supports SqlDependency will probably be a lot faster than *any* other  technique, but that still won't be as scaleable as a server sending SignalR or gRPC notifications to clients. Besides, to use SqlDependency/Message Broker you *need* an open database connection, all the time. With a server tier handling notifications, you don't

Comment: i used the SqlDependency class and whenever a change occur in a certain table the 
function that is linked with change event will use signalr hub to send the notification,
and the server will remain listening for any change and as you said the connection must still open. is that a good technique to use and dose it consume the server resources.